# Typescript Dynamics CRM window.parent

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm, crm, typescript-typings

Since I am using webresource in my CRM functionality I need to use

```
window.parent.Xrm.Page...etc
```

to access entity data.

Unfortunately, as I write in typescript, this construction won't compile. For now I just add `window.parent` before `Xrm.Page`...(I got Xrm typings) by hand but this is very far from TypeScript idea. Is there any way, some typings or so, that would let me call window.parent.Xrm in a normal, elegant way? I am using Visual Studio

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Property "Xrm" does not exist on type "Window". I am using Visual Studio

Comment: What if you write your typescript code so that you can pass a reference to the Xrm page, only, removing any dependencies on the window object, and then, once compiled, you call it from the CRM form passing the window.parent.Xrm.Page instance for example.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/xrm/xrm.d.ts For me it worked in this scenario...

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no way how to get around grabbing root reference via `window.Xrm` object, however you can encapsulate it so it happen just once.

If you're using correct ts templates - i.e.:

```
Install-Package xrm.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
```

It should be simple as

```
class Bar {
    constructor(private xrm: Xrm.XrmStatic) {}
    foo() {
        //work in strongly typed world
        //return this.xrm.Page....;
    }
}
```

And than just once initialize it like

```
var bar = new Bar(window.Xrm);  
bar.foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `(<any>window.parent).Xrm.` in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) to get an error free compile with `window.parent.Xrm`.  For example:

```
let nameAttr = (<any>window.parent).Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("name").getValue()
```